# Improving MySQL SELECT query speed of four huge (~100M rows) JOINed tables

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have the following query that is supposed to find extra information for each related record by a given `linker` number. For example this query finds `Title`, `Author`, and `Date` for all the documents that `linkTo` a single one with `linker=86sgv_ksg:0040608`.

```
SELECT 
    `r`.`linker`, 
    IF(`s`.`isSecond`='1', `c2`.`title`, `c1`.`title`) AS `Title`,
    IF(`s`.`isSecond`='1', `c2`.`author`, `c1`.`author`) AS `Author`,
    IF(`s`.`isSecond`='1', `c2`.`date`, `c1`.`date`) AS `Date`
FROM 
    (SELECT `linker` FROM `my_rel` WHERE `linkTo`='86sgv_ksg:0040608') `r` 
    INNER JOIN `my_stat` `s` ON `r`.`linker`=`s`.`linker`
    LEFT JOIN `my_content_1` `c1` ON (`s`.`isSecond`='0' AND `s`.`linker`=`c1`.`linker`)
    LEFT JOIN `my_content_2` `c2` ON (`s`.`isSecond`='1' AND `s`.`linker`=`c2`.`linker`);
```

This is the `EXPLAIN` results:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    38702   NULL    
1   PRIMARY s   eq_ref  Unique  Unique  767 r.linker    1   NULL    
1   PRIMARY c1  ref linker  linker  767 r.linker    1   Using where 
1   PRIMARY c2  ref linker  linker  767 r.linker    1   Using where 
2   DERIVED my_rel  ref Link    Link    767 const   38702   Using index condition
```

This query, depending on how many records are found takes quite a few seconds (almost one second per 1000 rows found)

```
# Query_time: 20.393228  Lock_time: 0.000115 Rows_sent: 19917  Rows_examined: 99672
```

with this server:

```
CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-6700
RAM: 64 GB DDR4
Hard Drive: 2 x 500 GB SATA 6 Gb/s 
    |_ SSD: Software-RAID 0 = 1000GB
```

and my OS (Linux) and MySQL DB are on SSD. But still the query take few seconds.

Table `my_rel` (~200M rows) holds all the relationships between documents and these documents are separated in two tables: `my_content_1` (~5M rows) and `my_content_2` (~65M rows) depending on their types. Table `my_stat` (~70M rows) identifies where each document is (in `my_content_1` or `my_content_2`). The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for these four tables are as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_content_1` /*similarly `my_content_2`*/ (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` text COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `author` tinytext COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `linker` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `linker` (`linker`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67654117 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED 

CREATE TABLE `my_rel` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `linker` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `linkTo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`linker`, `order`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `Link` (`linkTo`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=248383246 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

CREATE TABLE `my_stat` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `linker` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `isSecond` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`linker`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `isSecond` (`isSecond`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=111412100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Initially my query was like this:

```
SELECT 
    `r`.`linker`, 
    IF(`s`.`isSecond`='1', `c2`.`title`, `c1`.`title`) AS `Title`,
    IF(`s`.`isSecond`='1', `c2`.`author`, `c1`.`author`) AS `Author`,
    IF(`s`.`isSecond`='1', `c2`.`date`, `c1`.`date`) AS `Date`
FROM `my_rel` `r` 
    LEFT JOIN `my_stat` `s` ON `r`.`linker`=`s`.`linker`
    LEFT JOIN `my_content_1` `c1` ON (`s`.`isSecond`='0' AND `s`.`linker`=`c1`.`linker`)
    LEFT JOIN `my_content_2` `c2` ON (`s`.`isSecond`='1' AND `s`.`linker`=`c2`.`linker`)
WHERE `r`.`linkTo`='86sgv_ksg:0040608' AND `r`.`linker`!='86sgv_ksg:0040608' 
GROUP BY `r`.`linker` 
ORDER BY `Date` DESC;
```

and it was taking a little bit longer than my current query by doing grouping and ordering, which I removed to have better speed. The current query still take long time to do all the linkings.

Can my query be faster?

Comment: What indexes do you have? What is the query plan?

Comment: My indexes are shown in the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, right? What do you mean by "query plan"?

Comment: show the EXPLAIN of you query

Comment: I've added that, but I don't know how to make it more beautiful as a table like others do.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a both an `AUTO_INCREMENT` and a `UNIQUE` key, consider getting rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` and promoting the `UNIQUE` to be `PRIMARY`.  *Usually* this will

- Shrink disk footprint
- Speed up many queries against the table.

For `my_rel`,...

```
SELECT `linker` FROM `my_rel` WHERE `linkTo`='86sgv_ksg:0040608'

FROM `my_rel` `r` 
... ON `r`.`linker`...
WHERE `r`.`linkTo`='86sgv_ksg:0040608'
  AND `r`.`linker`!='86sgv_ksg:0040608'
```

Both of these beg for an index with `(linker, linkTo)`, which can be better served by changing from

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`linker`, `order`) USING BTREE,
KEY `Link` (`linkTo`) USING BTREE
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY (`linker`, `order`),
KEY (`linkTo`, linker)
```

Since we are looking at 38K records out of 200M, the bouncing from secondary key to primary key could be doing upwards of 38K disk hits, which might take 380 seconds on a spinning drive.  (Decrease that some due to caching, and it could get down to the entire 20 seconds you are experiencing.)

By having the 'composite' key I propose, that index is "covering", hence will hit the disk maybe 380 times instead of 38000 times.  This is potentially a 100x speedup (but 10x is more likely).

Once it gets to `c1` and `c2`, this change could save another 38K disk hits:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `linker` (`linker`) USING BTREE,
KEY `date` (`date`)
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY `linker` (`linker`),
KEY `date` (`date`)
```

While you are making those changes, consider lowering the `255` in any `VARCHARs`.  Furthermore, if linker values look like '86sgv_ksg:0040608', consider whether `linker` and `link_to` could be `CHARACTER SET ascii`.

Also, for `my_stat`...

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`linker`) USING BTREE,
KEY `isSecond` (`isSecond`)
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY (`linker`)
```

Note:  A single-column index on a flag (`isSecond`) is unlikely to ever be used.

(The default for InnoDB indexes is `BTree`.  The only exceptions are `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL`.)

Comment: The query you mentioned is my older one, which is improved to the one posted on the top of my question. Those `id` keys are used for other purposes, as well as the `isSecond` one. This query is not the only query I have om my website.

Comment: Let's see a use for `id` that could not be replaced by `linker`.  Because of cardinality, `INDEX(isSecond)` will never be used.  If this is wrong, please provide the `SELECT` and it's `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I'll try to modify the indexes as you suggested and will let you know how it went. But it'll take few days as tables are very huge and I need to be very cautious.

Comment: Rick, in a test table I converted `id` key to a regular index and `linker` to a primary one. Solely doing this increase the size of the table about 280%! (from 3.7Gb to 8.9Gb). Why is that happening? I cannot have this much increase in my tables size if this will happen to all of those huge tables (each are already 10s of Gbs)

Comment: @SAVAFA - But you now have redundant and/or unnecessary indexes; _they_ are taking the extra 5.2GB.  Well, maybe not totally...

Comment: Rick, everything is the same in my two test tables and the only difference is converting `linker` to primary and `id` to regular. This difference cause that much more space. Can this be correct?

Comment: Each secondary key has a copy of the PK.  So... `PK(id), U(linker), K(date)` has 3 copies of `id`, 2 of `linker`, 2 of `date`.  `PK(linker), K(date)` has no id, 2 `linker`, 2 `date` -- a small shrinkage by getting rid of `id`.  Keeping id (for other purposes):  `PK(linker), K(id) K(date)` has 2 id, 3 `linker`, 2 `date`.  Since `linker` is a lot fatter than `id`, this will increase the disk footprint.  But not by 280%! -- I think I need to see exactly what gives you 8.9GB.

Comment: I did test on 1000 rows of different main tables (three of them) imported into test tables and only switching `PK(id)` to `K(id)` and `U(linker)` to `PK(linker)` increases the size by around 200% more or less. Probably as you mentioned having copies of `PK(linker)` multiple times in different keys is causing this, as `linker` is much much bigger in size than `id`

Comment: @SAVAFA - Where there other secondary keys?  Yes, copies of `linker` is more bulky than copies of `id`.  And this is one argument for using `AUTO_INCREMENT` _in some cases_.  I provide answers for the _schema presented_; if this is a _simplified_ schema, then my answer may not be optimal.  Please start over, with the full schema and full query.

Comment: Rick, yes this is a simplified version of the schema but query is as it is (renamed though). What other info from the schema is necessary? Would only number of other fields and keys be enough?

Comment: I'm asking because `my_content_1` and `my_content_2` have many fields and other indexes

Comment: Any more help...?

Comment: @SAVAFA - Sometimes it is best to make changes like these in stages.  Please do what you can of my suggestions, then reevaluate the situation.  After that, I may have more suggestions.

Comment: @SAVAFA - As for "many fields and other indexes"...  I cannot say "one size fits all".  Find the next slowest query and let's see the field(s) and index(es) that are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

From the explain it seems the major problem here is the subquery not being indexed properly.
I would add the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_rel` ADD INDEX `my_rel_index_1` (`linkTo`, `linker`);
```

Also, I can see many places in the query where you're comparing numeric columns to strings. For example:

```
`s`.`isSecond` = '0'
```

I would avoid that and remove the quotes around '0' (in all places where you do the same). Such a comparison can cause implicit casts, which can prevent proper index usage for these filters.

Comment: On the contrary...  INT = '0' compiles OK; VARCHAR = 0 does not.

Comment: But isSecond is a tinyint according to the schema provided above, so why adding the quotes around 0?

Comment: An individual would not deliberately quote a number..  However, certain APIs "bind" values into the SQL, automatically adding quotes.  This is necessary for strings.  Since it is 'optional' for numeric literals, there is no real harm in doing so for them, too.  The API would get more complex if the quotes were not added, so there is an up side.

Comment: @Tomer I'll try to see how I can work on the '0' to remove single quotes. Regarding your proposed solution, the query that I'm using now, which is posted on top of my question, I no longer use `linker` in my WHERE clause. So I believe adding this index wouldn't help it at all, right?

Comment: @SAVAFA - `(SELECT `linker` FROM `my_rel` WHERE `linkTo`='86sgv_ksg:0040608')` would benefit from the composite index that Tomer recommends.

Comment: So, which of my two mentioned queries are supposed to work better, the first one or the second one? By my tests so far, the first one performs slightly better, but not much. Would adding the new index and using the second query be a lot faster and better?

Comment: I logged my query times after changing `'0'` to `0` and there was not noticeable improvement.